# Java threading - how to use the same TimerTask instance in all threads

Tags: java, multithreading, time, client, server

My (hopefully last) question about timed events and threading in Java. I have a Server application, which sends information to all clients about current Server time. I added a possiblity for a client to change Server time. However, the way it's currently implemented, every Client connection runs on a separate thread. And each of those threads has its own ClockTask instance. So even if time is modified by a client, it will only be modified in the ClockTask instance of this particular thread. Any other clients will still have their own, old time. My code:

Server - every time an incoming Client connects, a new thread is started.

```
public class Server {



 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        boolean listeningSocket = true;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(11111);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 11111");
        }


        while(listeningSocket){
            System.out.println("Waiting for a client to connect...");
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client connected!");
            ConnectThread ct = new ConnectThread(clientSocket);     

            ct.start();

        }
        System.out.println("closed");
        serverSocket.close();       
    }

}
```

ConnectThread - every connect thread has its own ClockTask (which is in fact a timer, updating time every second) :

```
public class ConnectThread extends Thread{

public static final int INTERVAL = 1000;

static ClockTask ctask;


private Socket socket = null;
public ConnectThread(Socket socket) {
   super("ConnectThread");
    this.socket = socket;


    if(this.ctask == null)
    {
        synchronized(ClockTask.class)
        {
             if(this.ctask == null)
             {
                 this.ctask = new ClockTask();
             }
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void run(){
    ObjectOutputStream serverOutputStream = null;
    ObjectInputStream serverInputStream = null;
    try {           
        serverOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());          
        serverInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());


        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(ctask, 0, INTERVAL);

        while(true)
        {
            Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
            System.out.println("mark");
            System.out.println(ctask.getTime());
            serverOutputStream.writeUTF(ctask.getTime());               
            serverOutputStream.flush();
            String ok = serverInputStream.readUTF();
            if(ok.equals("ok"))
            {

                String newTime = serverInputStream.readUTF();
                ctask.setCalendarTime(newTime);
            }

        }

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try {
            serverOutputStream.close();
            serverInputStream.close();              
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}
}
```

Clock task holds the time information:

```
public class ClockTask extends TimerTask {

private Calendar calendar;
private String time;

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}


public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}


public ClockTask()
{
    this.calendar = Calendar.getInstance(new Locale("us", "US"));

}


@Override
public void run() {

    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");                   
    this.time = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    //System.out.println(time);
}


public void setCalendarTime(String newTime)
{
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");   
    try {
        Date t = dateFormat.parse(newTime);
        calendar.setTime(t);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



}
```

And now, the first obvious method that came to my mind, would be to declare the ClockTask in the Server class, and then pass the object reference to any new ConnectThread, then modify it. But that didn't work, I got lots of data reading errors, also a problem with this is that it happens in static main method, so I can only access it in a static way. The only thing I know, is that it can't be created in every new ConnectThread instance. It has to be one object, existing somewhere outside. Any ideas?

EDIT 
Client:

```
public class Client {

private static final String REQUEST_TIME_CHANGE = "ok";


public static void main(String[] arg) {



    Socket socketConnection = null;
    ObjectOutputStream clientOutputStream = null;
    ObjectInputStream clientInputStream = null;

    ClockGUI gui = new ClockGUI();
    gui.setVisible(true);

    try {

        socketConnection = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 11111);

        clientOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
                socketConnection.getOutputStream());
        clientInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(
                socketConnection.getInputStream());     


        while(true){

            System.out.println("before\n");
            String date = clientInputStream.readUTF();      
            System.out.println(date);
            gui.cp.setDate(date);
            gui.repaint();

            if(gui.isTimeChanged())
            {
                clientOutputStream.writeUTF(REQUEST_TIME_CHANGE);
                clientOutputStream.flush();
                clientOutputStream.writeUTF(gui.getTime());
                clientOutputStream.flush();
                gui.setTimeChanged(false);
            }
            else{
                clientOutputStream.writeUTF("");
                clientOutputStream.flush();
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("The following exception has occured and was caught:");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally{
        try {
            clientOutputStream.close();
            clientInputStream.close();              
            socketConnection.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}




}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `ScheduledExecutorService`?

Comment: Well, mainly because I wasn't aware of its existence ;) How is it better?

Comment: Well, you can schedule "whatever you want" with it; furthermore, it is insensitive to system clock changes

Answer (score 0):

Make the variable static, so you only deal with one instance of it.

`private static ClockTask ctask;`

Use double checked locking to make sure that a single instance of ctask is created and maintained.

```
if(this.ctask == null)
{
    synchronized(ClockTask.class)
    {
         if(this.ctask == null)
         {
             this.ctask = new ClockTask();
         }
    }

}
```

You now get to change the same `Calendar` variable across multiple threads. You will of course have to deal with concurrency issues when more than one thread attempts to change the time.

Also, if you're going to mutate a state that is shared between multiple parties, you might as well do it in another class. `cTask` can be the reference that helps you mutate that state and the state itself (calendar time) can be represented by another class. That way you can launch multiple `cTask` instances that try to lock on the same calendar object to mutate it's state. That would be a better way to achieve what you're attempting.

Comment: But you mean to make it static in ConnectThread class? And this checking should be in the constructor?

Comment: Yes the constructor only instantiates one version of the task itself. That is one way to do it. My answer also mentions an alternate way.

Comment: Still, if I connect a new Client, there is an exception when trying to readUTF().

Comment: The client code not being able to read the stream is be a separate problem. It is easier to raise a separate question for that and detail the exception and problem there. Maintaining the same clock instance is possible with the suggestions I made. Your code also has bugs like this `ConnectThread ct = new ConnectThread(clientSocket); ct.start();`. You're not really starting a thread here. Discussing these problems will lead to a digression. Create another question about the error and post a stack trace and the community will help you get that running too.

Comment: Okay, but another truth is, that when I don't use your solution, it works fine. I'll raise the question, though. Thanks anyway

Comment: Suggestions are still welcom here, as I need to wait 90 minutes until I can post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You could annotate your class with the CDI annotation @Singleton

The other choice is to create a single thread for a timer:

static ScheduledExecutorService timer = 
       Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

and then something like this:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
         () -> doSomething(),0,1,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```